Sync is successful but data doesn't update in the salesforce backend
Within the soup , I have this Data :
{
  "cursorId": "0x60001174a400",
  "currentPageIndex": 0,
  "pageSize": 1000,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "totalEntries": 1,
  "currentPageOrderedEntries": [
    [
      {
        "__locally_created__": true,
        "DWM_Standard_Job_Number__c": "A000",
        "StartDate": "2024-04-10T17:12:05+05:30",
        "Description": "Jgjgjh",
        "DWM_WorkOrder_Work_Pack_Name__c": "Compressor: Gas Generator",
        "_soupEntryId": 1,
        "_soupLastModifiedDate": 1712749325791,
        "EndDate": "2024-04-10T17:12:05+05:30",
        "__locally_deleted__": false,
        "attributes": {
          "type": "WorkOrder"
        },
        "Status": "Completed",
        "__locally_updated__": false,
        "__local__": true,
        "DWM_Assigned_Resource__c": "0Hn8E00000050NaSAI"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

And I use the below code for sync up :
export async function syncUpAHWorkOrders() {
    if (syncInFlight) {
        console.log("Not starting syncUp - sync already in fligtht");
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
 
    console.log("Starting syncUp");
    syncInFlight = true;
    return syncUp(ADHOC_STORE_CONFIG_GLOBAL, {}, TABLE_AD_HOC, { mergeMode: mobilesync.MERGE_MODE.OVERWRITE, fields },
        async (syncStatus) => {
            syncInFlight = false;
            console.log("syncUpAHWorkOrders successs", syncStatus);
        }, async (error) => {
            console.log("syncUpAHWorkOrders error", error);
            syncInFlight = false;
        }
    )
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("syncUp completed or failed " + JSON.stringify(res));
            syncInFlight = false;
        });
 
}

I get following response :
SyncUpAHWorkOrders successs {
  "_soupEntryId": 1404,
  "endTime": 1712761455311,
  "error": "",
  "isGlobalStore": true,
  "maxTimeStamp": 0,
  "options": {
    "mergeMode": "OVERWRITE"
  },
  "progress": 100,
  "soupName": "WorkOrder",
  "startTime": 1712761455307,
  "status": "DONE",
  "storeName": "dwm_global_store",
  "target": {
    "iOSImpl": "SFCollectionSyncUpTarget",
    "idFieldName": "Id",
    "maxBatchSize": 200,
    "modificationDateFieldName": "LastModifiedDate",
    "type": "rest"
  },
  "totalSize": 0,
  "type": "syncUp"
}

As per the log above , the sync up is successful , but when I check in the backend , the data is not there. Please help!
Values of the constant variables:
const ADHOC_STORE_CONFIG_GLOBAL = { isGlobalStore: true, storeName: 'dwm_global_store' };
const TABLE_AD_HOC = 'WorkOrder';
const fields = [
 'DWM_WorkOrder_Work_Pack_Name__c', 'Description', 'Status', 'DWM_Standard_Job_Number__c',
 'DWM_Assigned_Resource__c']

This is how the soup is registered :
export function firstTimeSyncData() {
    return registerSoup(ADHOC_STORE_CONFIG_GLOBAL,
        TABLE_AD_HOC,
        fieldsWithType)
        .then(syncDownAHWorkOrders);
}

const fieldsWithType = [{ path: "Id", type: "string" },
{ path: "DWM_WorkOrder_Work_Pack_Name__c", type: "string" },
{ path: "Description", type: "full_text" },
{ path: "Status", type: "string" },
{ path: "DWM_Standard_Job_Number__c", type: "full_text" },
{ path: "DWM_Assigned_Resource__c", type: "string" },
{ path: "__local__", type: "string" }
]

